# What is the distribution of minimum of Brownian motion on arbitrary interval?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

We know that $P(\min_{0 \leq s\leq t} B_t \leq x)=2P(B_t\leq x)$. This can be found in any standard stochastic calculus textbook.

However I am curious about instead of the interval $[0,t]$ if we consider an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$. What will the distribution be then?

By law of total probability we have $P(\min_{a \leq s\leq b} B_t \leq x)=P(\min_{a \leq s\leq b} B_t \leq x|B(a)\geq x)$ then using Bayes' theorem we have that this is $P(\min_{a \leq s\leq b} B_t \leq x,B(a)\geq x)/P(B(a)\geq x)$. Then here I am stuck.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W_{a,b}:=\min_{a\le s\le b}B_s$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(W_{a,b}\le w)&=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(W_{a,b}-B_a\le w-B_a\mid B_a)]\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathsf{P}(W_{0,{b-a}}\le w-x)\phi(x;0,a)\,dx,
\end{align}
where $\phi(x;\mu,\sigma^2)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp\{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2\}$.

Comment: Hi I was just wondering if you could expand this out more afterward? I write this down and try to simplify but there's not much simplifications. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user658409 It is an integral involving normal cdf. I am not aware of any simplification of this expression; though, it can be computed numerically.

Comment: Thank you for your time.